# How can I locate source code by dll offset?

Tags: dll

I compiled freeimageplus into dll. the dll is used in by my application.
But I found memory leaking problem.
boundary check say: Leaking existing program  --> FreeImagePlus.dll!0x0005CD06。
I have pdb with the freeiamgeplus.dll. How can I locate the source code using the information "FreeImagePlus.dll!0x0005CD06"

Answer (score 2):

Put the dll and the pdb in the same directory and do

```
ildasm /LINENUM /SOURCE FreeImagePlus.dll
```

This should show the line number and source (if available) for each IL block.

```
  .line 12,12 : 13,37 ''  
//000012:             string s = "one string";  
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "one string"  
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
```

This shows that IL offset 1 and 6 map to line 12 columns 13-37

Comment: Uhm yes it should. Didn't you try it?